# hyperledger-fabric byfn.sh -m failed with script/scripts.sh not found

Tags: docker, hyperledger-fabric

I am running the byfn.sh script within docker container on windows 10.

Docker version 18.03.0-ce, build 0520e24302

I am getting the script.sh not found error message, please help.

$ ./byfn.sh -m up

```
Starting with channel 'mychannel' and CLI timeout of '10' seconds and CLI 
delay of '3' seconds
Continue? [Y/n] y
proceeding ...
2018-04-28 20:28:24.254 UTC [main] main -> INFO 001 Exiting.....
LOCAL_VERSION=1.1.0
DOCKER_IMAGE_VERSION=1.1.0
Starting peer1.org2.example.com ... done
Starting peer0.org2.example.com ... done
Starting peer1.org1.example.com ... done
Starting peer0.org1.example.com ... done
Starting orderer.example.com    ... done
cli is up-to-date
OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:348: starting container process caused "exec: \"scripts/script.sh\": stat scripts/script.sh: no such file or directory": unknown
ERROR !!!! Test failed
```

Answer (score 0):

Resolved the issue by copying the entire fabric-samples directory to c:\users\ directory.

Having the fabric-samples directory anywhere else on c:\ drive gives the error. Perhaps an explicit path needs to be defined somewhere if placing fabric-samples in any location other than c:\users\

Comment: What version of Windows?

Answer (score 0):

I figured that the volumes from the docker container under Windows are not correctly mounted (not at all). But I don't know how to fix it... I'll get back if I have more information on this issue or even a solution.